# Get application pool's memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I want to get my application pool's memory usage using Process class. This is my code so far:

```
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPoolCollection = serverManager.ApplicationPools;


            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(applicationPoolCollection.Where(p => p.Name == "mywebsite.com").First().WorkerProcesses[0].ProcessId);
```

I can get Process class but how do I know what is the amount of RAM it is using currently? I do see properties like `PagedMemorySize64` and `NonpagedSystemMemorySize64`. Which one would give me the correct RAM that it is occupying at the moment?

I cannot use `PerformanceCounter` like so:

```
PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

                performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";

                performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";

                performanceCounter.InstanceName = process.ProcessName;
 Console.WriteLine(((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"));
```

The reason being `ProcessName` would return w3p and therefore PerformanceCounter would write the total IIS RAM usage in Console which is not what I want.

I just need the application pool's RAM usage. Therefore I think my answer lies in Process class and not PerformanceCounter

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need amount of RAM, or amount of memory assigned to the process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need simply amount of ram visible to the process, which means amount of ram assigned to the process, but not necessary  that every single bit of it is actually used by the process, you can use: [WorkingSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset(v=vs.110).aspx). (Choose appropriate version for your .net)

Just invite your attention on the fact, that there is much more into process memory diagnostics, in case you might be concerned about allocated Virtual Memory, Commited Memory, Mapped Files and whatnot.

Comment: Thank you. I need the amount of RAM shown in task manager for eg: if in Task manager the memory usage  is shown as 290 MB the code should give me that (obviously need to divide by 1024 * 1024). I tried your property of WorkingSet however there is difference  between that and the task manager. Working set usually returns more memory than what is shown in task manager. Any idea why would this happen?

Comment: try to use [PrivateMemorySize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64(v=vs.110).aspx)